# Pandas DataFrame: categorical dtype to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, categorical-data, timedelta

I have a df with column "time_gap" which has a `categoricalDtype`:

```
CategoricalDtype(categories=['0 days 00:00:00', '0 days 01:00:00', '0 days 02:00:00',
                  '0 days 03:00:00', '0 days 04:00:00', '0 days 05:00:00',
                  '0 days 06:00:00', '0 days 07:00:00', '0 days 08:00:00',
                  '0 days 09:00:00', '0 days 10:00:00', '0 days 11:00:00',
                  '0 days 12:00:00', '0 days 13:00:00', '0 days 14:00:00',
                  '0 days 15:00:00', '0 days 16:00:00', '0 days 17:00:00',
                  '0 days 18:00:00', '0 days 19:00:00', '0 days 20:00:00',
                  '0 days 21:00:00', '0 days 22:00:00', '0 days 23:00:00'],
, ordered=True)
```

--> **hours:minutes:seconds**

I would like to convert it to a datetime dtype (and ideally get rid of the "0 days").

When I try using `df["time_gap"] = pd.to_datetime(df["time_gap"])`, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas.Timedelta'> is not convertible to datetime, at position 0
```

Is there an easy way to convert this categoricalDtype to datetime?

Thank you in advance for your feedbacks.

Comment: add the timedelta to a pd.Timestamp, i.e. a reference date?

Comment: Hello, do you have an example on how to do this?

Comment: you'd basically just add the series to a Timestamp; something like `df["datetime"] = pd.Timestamp("2022-01-01") + df["time_gap"].astype("timedelta64[ns]")` (date is arbitrary)

Comment: Thank you. I already have a column with date and here, I would like to only have the hour, minute and second in this column (so getting rid of the "0 days" in a datetime format.

Comment: pandas does not tread date and time separately; there is only a datetime dtype natively. You could use the time dtype from vanilla Python but would only give you and object type column which doesn't offer the functionality a datetime type column (series) offers.

Comment: Ok thank you, so basically, since all minutes and seconds are equal to 00 (only the hour changes), it would be best if I have a column with only the hour? I think in that case the dt.hour should do the trick but I don't know how to convert it from a categorical data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here're two options how you could access the 'hours' from the categorial column:

```py
import pandas as pd

# dummy data -->
df = pd.DataFrame({"time_gap":['0 days 00:00:00', '0 days 01:00:00', '0 days 02:00:00',
                  '0 days 03:00:00', '0 days 04:00:00', '0 days 05:00:00',
                  '0 days 06:00:00', '0 days 07:00:00', '0 days 08:00:00',
                  '0 days 09:00:00', '0 days 10:00:00', '0 days 11:00:00',
                  '0 days 12:00:00', '0 days 13:00:00', '0 days 14:00:00',
                  '0 days 15:00:00', '0 days 16:00:00', '0 days 17:00:00',
                  '0 days 18:00:00', '0 days 19:00:00', '0 days 20:00:00',
                  '0 days 21:00:00', '0 days 22:00:00', '0 days 23:00:00']
})

df["time_gap"] = pd.to_timedelta(df["time_gap"]).astype("category")
# <-- dummy data

# via timedelta:
df["hour"] = df["time_gap"].astype("timedelta64[ns]").dt.total_seconds()/3600

# via datetime:
df["hour_"] = (pd.Timestamp("2022-01-01") + df["time_gap"].astype("timedelta64[ns]")).dt.hour
```

```py
print(df)
          time_gap  hour  hour_
0  0 days 00:00:00   0.0      0
1  0 days 01:00:00   1.0      1
2  0 days 02:00:00   2.0      2
3  0 days 03:00:00   3.0      3
4  0 days 04:00:00   4.0      4
5  0 days 05:00:00   5.0      5
...
```

```py
# note that .dt.hour gives you an integer:
print(df.dtypes)
time_gap    category
hour         float64
hour_          int32
dtype: object
```